# Regular Expression to match more than one occurrence of a character

Tags: java, regex

I need help coming up with a regular expression to match if a string has more than one occurrence of character. I already validated the length of the two strings and they will always be equal. Heres what i mean, for example. The string "aab" and "abb". These two should match the regular expression because they have repeating characters, the "aa" in the first string and the "bb" in the second.

Comment: nope, it would not. I am using this to solve an anagram problem and aba could be written as baa or aab. The first string i have given, is the source string and the second would be the one that needs to be tested and as you can see they are not anagrams

Comment: Since `perl` has nothing to do with this question, I removed the `perl` tag. If you really need to have it in, then please elaborate the reasoning for adding the `perl` tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you say "aba"-style repetition doesn't count, back-references should make this simple:

```
(.)\1+
```

Would find sequences of characters. Try it out:

```
java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(.)\\1+").matcher("b").find(); // false
java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(.)\\1+").matcher("bbb").find(); // true
```

Comment: What did you copy & paste? Note that when you use the regex in a Java string you need to escape certain characters (see the Java code I posted, which runs for me here).

Comment: the `-> false` and `-> true` parts are not part of the code, are you copying them?

Comment: i didn't need the values to be hard coded though, because the strings could be any value i just used those two as an example.

Answer (score 2):

If you're checking anagrams maybe a different algorithm would be better.

If you sort your strings (both the original and the candidate), checking for anagrams can be done with a string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
static final String REGEX_MORE_THAN_ONE_OCCURANCE_OF_B = "([b])\\1{1,}";
static final String REGEX_MORE_THAN_ONE_OCCURANCE_OF_B_AS_PREFIX_TO_A = "(b)\\1+([a])";
```